# Multiple AND and OR condition in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I having trouble with elasticsearch query.

Data Structrue:
`[{agent : "abc", origin: "US"}, {agent : "abc", origin: "US"}`

I'm not able to find multiple agent name (OR condition) and (AND Condition) multiple Origin (OR condition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `terms` already has OR semantics, you don't need to wrap them in `bool/should` queries. The following query should do what you expect:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "agent": [
              "agent1",
              "agent2"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "origin": [
              "US",
              "CA"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of [`bool/must/should`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) clause along with the [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html)

```
    {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "agent": [
              "abc",
              "abc"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "origin": [
              "US",
              "US"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```